# Reversing every character in a file

Tags: language-agnostic, character, endianness

I'm in a little trouble here.

Can anyone help me implement a solution that reverses every byte so 0xAB becomes 0xBA but **not** so "abcd" becomes "dcba". I need it so AB CD EF becomes BA DC FE.

Preferably in C or C++ but it doesn't really matter provided it can run.

So far, I've implemented a UBER CRAPPY solution that doesn't even work (and yes, I know that converting to string and back to binary is a crappy solution) in PureBasic.

```
OpenConsole()
filename$ = OpenFileRequester("Open File","","All types | *.*",0)
If filename$ = ""
End
EndIf
OpenFile(0,filename$)
*Byte = AllocateMemory(1)
ProcessedBytes = 0
Loc=Loc(0)
Repeat
FileSeek(0,Loc(0)+1)
PokeB(*Byte,ReadByte(0))
BitStr$ = RSet(Bin(Asc(PeekS(*Byte))),16,"0")
FirstStr$ = Left(BitStr$,8)
SecondStr$ = Right(BitStr$,8)
BitStr$ = SecondStr$ + FirstStr$
Bit.b = Val(BitStr$)
WriteByte(0,Bit)
ProcessedBytes = ProcessedBytes + 1
ClearConsole()
Print("Processed Bytes: ")
Print(Str(ProcessedBytes))
Loc=Loc(0)
Until Loc = Lof(0)
Delay(10000)
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Who gets homework on 31 Dec???

Answer (score 8):

Reading your PureBasic code (I skipped it at first), it does seem you want to swap endian, even though it's not what your text is asking—0xAB practically always means a byte with decimal value 171, not two bytes, and it's extremely common to display a byte as two hex digits, where you use A-F in your example.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  for (char a; cin.get(a);) {
    char b;
    if (!cin.get(b)) {
      cout.put(a); // better to write it than lose it
      cerr << "Damn it, input ends with an odd byte, is it in "
        "the right format?\n";
      return 1;
    }
    cout.put(b);
    cout.put(a);
  }
  return 0;
}
// C version is a similar easy translation from the original code
```

---

```
import numpy
import sys
numpy.fromfile(sys.stdin, numpy.int16).byteswap(True).tofile(sys.stdout)
```

---

*Original answer:*

I'm not sure why you want this (it **doesn't convert endian**, for example, if you want that), but here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  for (char c; (c == getchar()) != EOF;) {
    putchar((c & 0xF << 4) | ((int)c & 0xF0 >> 4));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  for (char c; std::cin.get(c);) {
    std::cout.put((c & 0xF << 4) | ((int)c & 0xF0 >> 4));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  sys.stdout.write("".join(
    chr((ord(c) & 0xF << 4) | (ord(c) & 0xF0 >> 4))
    for c in line
  ))
```

All assume that text translations don't occur (such as `\n` to `\r\n` and vice versa); you'll have to change them to opening files in binary mode if that's the case.  They read from stdin and write to stdout, if you're unfamiliar with that, so just use `programname < inputfile > outputfile` to run them.

Comment: I feel like we should just keep adding to this answer, so here, have a one-liner: `perl -ne 'print chr($_ & 15 << 4) | ($_ & 240 >> 4) for map ord, split //, $_'`

Answer (score 2):

Reversing the high and low half-byte is possible through a simple arithmetic formula (assuming you operate on unsigned bytes):

```
reversed = (original % 16) * 16 + (original / 16);
```

Comment: Just be careful of sign issues (this is the reason for the casts in my answer), which applies with both arithmetic and bitwise operations.  (255 -> -1, -1 / 16 is 0, not 15)

Answer (score 0):

A Haskell solution:

```
module ReverseBytes where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

-----------------------------------------------------------

main :: IO ()
main = B.getContents >>= B.putStr . B.map reverseByte

reverseByte :: Word8 -> Word8
reverseByte = flip rotate 4
```

---

```
runghc ReverseBytes.hs < inputfile > outputfile
```